# How do I describe the analytic completion to the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis

Is it possible?

I'm using the algebra generated by the set $\{0, 1^r\}$ for all fractions $r$ as my representation of the algebraic closure to $\mathbb{F}_2$.  I can't seem to find a metric on it.

What I've tried:

If I define $x^0 = 0$ (I know, odd, but not impossible), then I can find a "Newton's Method" on the polynomials over the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_2$.  With this choice, NM converges for many polynomials, such as $x^2 + x + 1$.  However, I still don't have a general theory of convergence, and my choice $x^0 = 0$ seems like it should be unnecessary.

Comment: There is always the discrete metric. Presumably, you are looking for a metric satisfying certain properties in order to exclude this, but you do not tell us which...

Comment: $\Bbb F^2$ is algebraicly closed. It has exactly four polynomials: $0$, $1$, $x$ and $x + 1$. All other polynomials reduce to one of these 4. The non-constant polynomials both have roots, so the field is closed. You have a closed extension of the $\Bbb F^2$, but it is not the algebraic closure.

Comment: According to http://planetmath.org/algebraicclosureofafinitefield (as well as what I remember from my Field Theory class), the Algebraic Closure of F2 has many more polynomials than 0, 1, x, and x+ 1, as well as roots to them.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez the Newton's Method algorithm should always converge.

Comment: @Luke, I have no idea what that means. Maybe it would be a good iddea for you to edit the question and *explain* what you want.